# Python how to eliminate 3 or more consequent letter

Tags: python

I am trying to replace those words which had continuous letters more than 3 example realllllly to really.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(.)\1\1{2,}", re.DOTALL)
return pattern.sub(r"\1\1\1", text)
```

I can't get it work anyone can help?

Comment: Your solution works with python 3.2, what's the issue?

Comment: I got one string is yummmy which doesn't replace to yummy

Comment: I am using python 2.7 does it affect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution actually appears to be working correctly:

```python
>>> import re
>>> a = 'foooooooo baaaar'
>>> reg = re.compile( r"(.)\1\1{2,}")
>>> reg.sub(r'\1\1', a)
'foo baar'
```

But based on comment, you want to replace `xyyyx` by `xyyx`, but you've specified regexp for at least 4 of them, therefor only `xyyyyx` gets replaced... Simply change this line:

```python
>>> reg = re.compile( r"(.)\1{2,}")
>>> reg.sub(r'\1\1', 'fooo baaaar actuallly')
'foo baar actually'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not to use regular expressions when they're not necessary. This task can be accomplished easily without, in a more readable fashion, with linear time and constant space complexity (not sure about the regex).

```
def filter_repetitions(text, max_repetitions=0):
    last_character = None
    repetition_count = 0
    for character in text:
        if character == last_character:
            repetition_count += 1
        else:
            last_character = character
            repetition_count = 0
        if repetition_count <= max_repetitions:
            yield character

print ''.join(filter_repetitions("fooo baaaar actuallly", 1))
```